# Could not find the LibVLCAttribute (UniversalMediaPlayer Asset)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, libvlc

This is a bit long so please bear with me.

I bought an asset last week from Unity Asset Store which is [ump-pro-android-ios](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ump-pro-android-ios-83283) and [ump-pro-win-mac-linux-webgl](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ump-pro-win-mac-linux-webgl-83281) . I followed the rules of combining the two asset into one . So here's the thing. I have this error

> Exception: Could not find the LibVLCAttribute.
>   UMP.InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate[libvlc_media_get_stats] (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/InteropLibraryLoader.cs:149)
>   Rethrow as MissingMethodException: The address of the function '' does not exist in 1721499648 library.
>   UMP.InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate[libvlc_media_get_stats] (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/InteropLibraryLoader.cs:173)
>   UMP.VlcMethods.LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/VlcMethods.cs:59)
>   Rethrow as ArgumentException: No suitable libvlc could be found in the provided path: The address of the function '' does not exist in 1721499648 library.
>   Parameter name: libvlcDirectory
>   UMP.VlcMethods.LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/VlcMethods.cs:64)
>   UMP.VlcMethods..ctor () (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/VlcMethods.cs:41)
>   UMP.VlcMethods.get_Instance () (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/VlcMethods.cs:19)
>   DealerLiveCam+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/DealerLiveCam.cs:201)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
>   UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
>   DealerLiveCam:OnPrepared(Texture2D) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/DealerLiveCam.cs:154)
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent`1:Invoke(T0)
>   UniversalMediaPlayer:OnPlayerPrepared(Texture2D) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/UniversalMediaPlayer.cs:1151)
>   UMP.PlayerManagerEvents:CallEvent() (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/Players/Managers/PlayerManagerEvents.cs:147)
>   UMP.c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/Players/Managers/PlayerManagerEvents.cs:118)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)

Which leads me to the asset script **InteropLibrary.cs**

```
var attrs = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InteropFunctionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("Could not find the LibVLCAttribute.");
```

**VLCMETHOD.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UMP.Wrappers;

//http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html

namespace UMP
{
public class VlcMethods
{
    private static VlcMethods instance = null;
    public static VlcMethods Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new VlcMethods();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int libvlc_media_get_stats(IntPtr p_md, out libvlc_media_stats_t p_stats);
    public libvlc_media_get_stats Libvlc_media_get_stats;

    public VlcMethods()
    {
        var libraryExtension = string.Empty;
        var settings = UMPSettings.Instance;

        if (UMPSettings.SupportedPlatform == UMPSettings.Platforms.Linux && settings.UseExternalLibs)
            libraryExtension += ".5";

        IntPtr handler = InteropLibraryLoader.Load(Wrapper.LibraryVLCName, settings.UseExternalLibs, settings.AdditionalLibsPath, libraryExtension);
        if (handler != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary(handler);
        }
    }

    ~VlcMethods()
    {
        instance = null;
    }

    private void LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary(IntPtr handler)
    {
        if (handler == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        try
        {
            //Libvlc_media_get_stats = (libvlc_media_get_stats)InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate<libvlc_media_get_stats>(handler);
            //[Pk Recode 29/12 2017]
            Libvlc_media_get_stats = InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate<libvlc_media_get_stats>(handler);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            InteropLibraryLoader.Unload(handler);
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format("No suitable " + Wrapper.LIBRARY_VLC_NAME + " could be found in the provided path: {0}", exception.Message),
                Wrapper.LIBRARY_VLC_NAME + "Directory", exception);
        }
    }
}
}
```

When i build it on **PC** my Streaming Method is Working now when i tried it on **Android** it doesn't work it tells me this error on **Logcat**

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>                                             at UMP.MediaPlayer.set_Mute (Boolean value) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at UniversalMediaPlayer.OnPathPrepared (System.String path, Boolean playImmediately) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at UniversalMediaPlayer+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
>                                             at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in :0 
>                                           UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine_Auto_Internal(IEnumerator)
>                                           UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
>                                           UniversalMediaPlayer:Play()
>                                           DealerLiveCamAndroid:Update()

Here is the code on my **DealerLiveCamAndroid.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UMP;

public class DealerLiveCamAndroid : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField]
GameObject ump; // lets access the ump gameobject
[SerializeField]
GameObject dealercam; //dealer cam for pc

void Update()
{
    if (tzPlayInfo.Instance.BLOCK_GAME_FLOW == false)
    {
        //find the gameobject through getting the child of every component/gameobject
        ump = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).GetChild(1).gameObject;
        dealercam = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(1).GetChild(0).gameObject;

        if (ump != null && dealercam != null)
        {
            //deactivate the dealercam for pc
            //dealercam.GetComponent<DealerLiveCam>().enabled = false;
            //Uses an If directives for the platform dependencies
        #if UNITY_ANDROID

            ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform = 2;
            var path = "***********/live/DEALER";
            if (ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform == 2)
            {
                //set the path
                ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._path = path;
                Debug.Log("Path has been found : " + ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._path);
                ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>().Play();
                Debug.Log("Now Media Is Playing");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't set the property to Android");
            }

        #elif UNITY_STANDALONE
            ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform = 0;
             //temporary path for the streaming
            var path = "rtmp://**********/live/DEALER";

            if(ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._chosenPlatform == 0){
                Debug.Log("UMP property is set to StandAlone/Windows");
                ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>()._path = path;
                //set the Streaming to autoplay
                ump.GetComponent<UniversalMediaPlayer>().Play();
                this.enabled = false;
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Couldn't set the property to StandAlone/Windows");
            }
        #else
        #endif
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Could not get the gameobject UMP");
        }
    }
}
}
```